# Injecting date into filename

Tags: bash

I am recursively working through a directory, finding files with a specific extension and inserting date.  I'm new to BASH and am getting tired of close, but not quite solutions.

```
for file in $(find $1 -name '*.xyz')
do
  echo "Modifying $file";

  ***CHANGE file here.  For example $file = file1.xyz.  move this to "file1_140102.xyz"***

done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.txt
do
  echo "Modifying $file"

  name=`echo "$file" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  ext=`echo "$file" | cut -d'.' -f2`
  mv $file "$name"_`date +%Y%m%d`".$ext"
done
```

Comment: `touch` won't rename a file for you.

Comment: Yeah, thought I'd just give a nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use command substitution inside the for loop for the reasons explained here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Use a while loop istead.

Assuming you want to add the current date before the file extension you can do

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.xyz' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    no_ext="${filename%.*}"
    mv "$filename" "${no_ext}_$(date +%y%m%d).${extension}"      
done
```

Comment: Perhaps using date? `mv "$filename" "${no_ext}_$(date +%y%m%d).${extension}"`

Comment: @onionjake Right. I didn't realize that 140102 is the current date backwards :)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ``done < <(find ...)`` so that the whole thing is not running in the subshell? Also you have to add ``--`` to mv command.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this but it should work, you can do something like this:

```
    DATE=`date "+%y%m%d"`

    for file in $(find "$1" -name '*.xyz'); 
    do 

       echo "Modifying $file";
       BASE=`basename $file .xyz`;
       mv ./$file ./$BASE_$DATE.xyz;
    done
```

Comment: that works well except I lose the path in the name and write the file at top level.  What command gives my the path of the file?

Comment: @user3155129 You can use the `dirname` command for that

Comment: In the mv line try this:

mv ./$file ./$BASE_$DATE.xyz;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, there is no need for `find` here; you can use the `globstar` option instead.

```
for f in "$1"/**/*.xyz; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.xyz}_$(date +%y%m%d).xyz"
done
```

As a matter of taste, you could also use the following for the new file name:

```
"$(date +${f%.xyz}_%y%m%d.xyz)"
```

The date format is really an arbitrary string in which percent-escapes are expanded, so you can have the "date" be a filename.